# a problrm when i turn a html form inputs into php array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, random

My html file contains the following form

```
<form action="action.php" method="get">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name[]" /><br>
    Second name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name[]" /><br>
    Third name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name[]" /><br>
    Forth name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name[]" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and I want the output to be one random value of the inputs , so my action.php looks like

```
<?php

    $output = $_POST['name'];

    $key = array_rand($output);
    echo $output[$key];

?>
```

but this doesn't work and gives me the following

**Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\myfiles\action.php on line 8**

**Warning: array_rand() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\myfiles\action.php on line 10**

can any one help please?

Comment: your method is "GET" why you use "$_POST" ?

Comment: change the `form` method to post: `method="post"`

Comment: @RyanAW you are right, my bad, thank you

Comment: @JosanIracheta thank you

Answer (score 1):

the form is submitted using **get** method

so you should use **$_GET** to retrieve sent datas like this:

```
<?php
     $output = $_GET['name'];
     $key = array_rand($output);
     echo $output[$key];
?>
```